# license creation getting invalid key how to make check.php from this code i have getting error

Tags: php, string, timestamp, signature, encryption

any body know that how to make `check.php` to verify the product key

when i check what are posting on `check.php` here the logs of method post

```
Sun, 18 May 2014 07:35:13 +0000a:6 {
 s:  1: "u";
 s: 44: "voN92KcXNxXQE1VrV+Muq4T/KuwziiyOT8rhwpcLZko=";
 s:  1: "t";
 s: 10: "1400398513";
 s:  1: "p";
 s: 88: "TVWb+BMcajJlu4+We5RfkCEMSRnvSjjx1pqTMuLRBftnWYkSJ2tMZuVezul2sYC5uXMW+qLLKJ7r87F5Cmp7QA==";
 s:  1: "k";
 s: 24: "493ppO3G+CVNZB0g3g6K2w==";
 s:  1: "i";
 s:128: "G133zJt4a1Csa+/LYCb7Q6NVvSNABx/Hyh3VxokaQy6AB/4vMxwSzh651jN+H5EBB3JCN54W2bzgBrEV3d7IpEfope3gO8iep9EbMDPujrlM5OSnLIdZx2g1aBLBGHLv";
 s:  1: "v";
 s: 24: "0rL3Iq61TBoDUi5piGG//A==";
}
```

and here is php code of that file if any body know how to make `check.php` please help me thanks

```
<?php

class Time {
    protected $productKey = '';
    protected $signature = null;
    protected $expiry = 864000;
    protected $installed = false;
    protected $timestamp = 0;
    protected $url = '';

    /**
     * License object constructor
     *
     * @access       public
     */
    public function __construct($productKey = array())
    {
        $this->url = 'http://www.example.com';

        if (is_file(VISICHAT_ROOT . DS . 'config.php')) {
            if (0 < filesize(VISICHAT_ROOT . DS . 'config.php')) {
                $this->installed = true;
                $productKey = Factory::getClass('config')->license;
            }
        }

        $this->productKey = $productKey;
        $this->fetchSignature();
    }

    /**
     * Check whether the license is valid
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        if ($this->getClass() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->getClass()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Downloads PHP class from the example server
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function fetchSignature()
    {
        if ($this->signature == null) {
            $timestamp = 343;

            if ($this->installed) {
                $timestamp = Factory::getClass('Setting')->getNumber('signature_timestamp');
            }

            if ($timestamp < time() - $this->expiry) {
                $this->timestamp = time();
                $ch = curl_init();
                $postdata = '&u=' . $this->encryptQuery(VIDEOCHAT_URL) . '&t=' . $this->timestamp . '&p=' . $this->encryptQuery(__FILE__) . '&k=' . $this->encryptQuery($this->productKey) . '&i=' . $this->encryptQuery(php_uname()) . '&v=' . $this->encryptQuery(Factory::getVersion());

                if ($this->installed) {
                    $postdata .= '&d=' . $this->encryptQuery(Factory::getClass('config')->database) . '&a=' . $this->encryptQuery(Factory::getClass('Setting')->get('chat_app'));
                }

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'license.example.com/check.php');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'example');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                $this->signature = curl_exec($ch);

                if ($this->installed) {
                    $setting = Factory::getClass('Setting');
                    $setting->saveProperty('signature', $this->signature);
                    $setting->saveProperty('signature_timestamp', $this->timestamp);
                }

                curl_close($ch);
            }
            else {
                $this->signature = Factory::getClass('Setting')->get('signature');
            }
        }

        return $this->signature;
    }

    /**
     * Get the signature object
     *
     * @return class
     */
    public function getClass()
    {
        $failedMessage = 'License verification failed.<br />Please double check your license details at: <a href=\'https://www.example.com/customers/\' target=\'_blank\'>example Customers Portal</a>';
        $signature = $this->fetchSignature();

        if (0 < strlen($signature)) {
            $signature = $this->decrypt($signature);
        }

        if (substr(trim($signature), 0, 5) == 'class') {
            if (!class_exists('Signature')) {
                eval($signature);
            }

            if (class_exists('Signature')) {
                $object = new Signature();

                if ($this->installed) {
                    $setting = Factory::getClass('Setting');
                    $setting->saveProperty('update_contents_field', $object->getNotification());
                }

                return $object;
            }

            if ($this->installed) {
                $setting = Factory::getClass('Setting');
                $setting->saveProperty('update_contents_field', '<span class=\'expired\'>' . $failedMessage . '</span>');
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->installed) {
                $setting = Factory::getClass('Setting');
                $setting->saveProperty('update_contents_field', '<span class=\'expired\'>' . $failedMessage . '</span>');
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Encrypt the raw data
     *
     * @return decrypted string
     */
    public function decrypt($data)
    {
        if (strlen($data) == 0) {
            return '';
        }

        return openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes128', $this->getPassword(), false, $this->getIV());
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt the query string data before posting
     *
     * @return decrypted string
     */
    public function encryptQuery($data)
    {
        return urlencode(openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes128', substr(md5($this->url . $this->timestamp), 0, 16), false, substr(sha1($this->timestamp . $this->url), 0, 16)));
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt the data with the given key
     *
     * @return encrypted data
     */
    public function hashToken($token)
    {
        $code = $this->getClass()->getCode();

        if ($code == '') {
            $code = rand(10000000, 90000000);
        }

        return sha1($token . $code);
    }

    /**
     * Get the initialization vector for the AES function
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIV()
    {
        $signature = $this->productKey . $this->getVideoChatURL() . 'example';
        return substr(sha1(md5($signature) . $signature . 'example.com'), 0, 16);
    }

    /**
     * Get the initialization vector for the AES function
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        $timestamp = $this->timestamp;

        if ($this->installed) {
            $timestamp = Factory::getClass('Setting')->getNumber('signature_timestamp');
        }

        $signature = $this->productKey . $this->getVideoChatURL() . __FILE__ . 'example' . $timestamp;
        return sha1(sha1($signature . 'example.com') . $signature . 'www.example.com');
    }

    /**
     * Get the video chat URL in format of http://yoursite.com/ (removes www.)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVideoChatURL()
    {
        $videoChatURL = VIDEOCHAT_URL;

        if (substr($videoChatURL, 0, 8) == 'https://') {
            if (substr($videoChatURL, 0, 12) == 'https://www.') {
                $videoChatURL = 'https://' . substr($videoChatURL, 12);
            }
        } else {
            if (substr($videoChatURL, 0, 7) == 'http://') {
                if (substr($videoChatURL, 0, 11) == 'http://www.') {
                    $videoChatURL = 'http://' . substr($videoChatURL, 11);
                }
            }
        }

        if (substr($videoChatURL, -1) != '/') {
            $videoChatURL .= '/';
        }

        return $videoChatURL;
    }
}

if (!(defined('VISICHAT_START'))) {
    exit('Access Denied');
    (bool)true;
}

?>
```

Comment: this is main php file from posting key on to this verify key from this i want to who can make check.php for valid key and signature timestamp generate like geniune see source from this and make a check.php i want it thanks i dont know much english i hope you understand